# How to use different events across many web browsers

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, browser

I'm working on an application and I want to create multiple threads, each thread must create a `WebBrowser`, every `WebBrowser` of these uses the method `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted`.

How can each of the created `WebBrowser` instances have it's own `DocumentCompleted` handler instead of the same `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted` method across all of them.

I explain :

in one case, an operation with a single web browser

```
int a = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            methode1();
        }
private void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (a == 1) methode2(wb);
            if (a == 2) methode2(wb);
        }

public void methode1()
        {
            webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.test.com");
            a = 1;
        }
public void methode2()
        {
            HtmlElement txt1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tesxtbox1");
            txt1.SetAttribute("value", "test");
            webBrowser.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");
            a = 2;
        }
public void methode3()
        {
            webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.test3.com");
        }
```

but if I want to make multiple operation, ie in butoon1 I add :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<5  ;i++)
            methode1();
        }
```

then to do it, I think I must have several webbrowser, so the solution is to create a thread for each operation

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<5  ;i++)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(methode1));
                thread.Start();
            }   
        }
```

So each web browser created by a thread must have its own method `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted`, to not be confused between the results of other web browser.

or, use the same method `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted` for all created web browser, but the problem is how to specify which webbrowser, call the method webBrowser_DocumentCompleted.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Quite easily, change the name of the method.

When you're creating your `WebBrowser`, you can assign `DocumentCompleted` to be any method that you want, for example:

```
firstWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += firstDocumentCompleted;
secondWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += secondDocumentCompleted;
thirdWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += thirdDocumentCompleted;
```

If you're using the designer, it's just as simple. In the Events tab, simply type a new (unique) method name.

Since you mentioned threading, I do envisage one problem if you don't pre-empt the amount of web browsers (and thus event handlers) you're going to have. But we'd need more specific use case examples if you want help with that.

Comment: This. Of course, it assumes that the code already exists, but if it doesn't, the OP has other problems that need solving first. `:)`

Comment: thanks Rudi Visser, I update my question for more explanation

Comment: @AbdelkarimTinguer I'm not sure I see exactly what you are doing at a glance, but if the code can be written in such a way that one (possibly parameterized) method will do the job but a single event handler cannot, look into *anonymous functions*. `webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (obj,e) => { Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString()); };` (the syntax may be slightly off but you get the idea) Then this answer will still be valid.